# C# ConcurrentBag memory consumption when iterating

Tags: c#, list, memory, foreach

It's easier if I start by posting the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<double> testLst = new List<double>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20000000; i++) { testLst.Add(i); }
```

I've populated a List with 20,000,000 elements. I see in the Task Manager that the process is using ~300MB. If I iterate through the list using a foreach loop:

```
    foreach (var a in testLst.Take(10)) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
}
```

memory usage does not increase (I've put a breakpoint on Console.WriteLine and, as I said, I'm measuring it using the Task Manager). Now, if I replace the List with a ConcurrentBag:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ConcurrentBag<double> testCB = new ConcurrentBag<double>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20000000; i++) { testCB.Add(i); }

    foreach (var a in testCB.Take(10)) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
}
```

memory usage is 450~500MB before the foreach-loop. The question is: why if inside the foreach-loop usage jumps to ~900MB?

I expect the ConcurrentBag to consume more memory compared to the List, but I don't understand why so much memory is being used for the iteration.

(I'm using the ConcurrentBag in a similar but different scenario, I know that in this case it would not make sense to use it)

Comment: ConcurrentBag would need to take some sort of snapshot when creating iterators - so higher memory usage seem reasonable. Check reference source code to see details...

Comment: Long story short: *never* iterate a thread-safe collection.  It gobbles memory *and* the values you get are often stale.   If you need predictable outcomes then there's no substitute for the *lock* keyword.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [`ConcurrentBag.GetEnumerator` docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381960.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> The enumeration represents a **moment-in-time snapshot** of the contents of the bag. It does not reflect any updates to the collection after `GetEnumerator` was called. The enumerator is safe to use concurrently with reads from and writes to the bag.

Looking at the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/collections/concurrent/ConcurrentBag.cs,1dd79ff6a9152ce3,references), you can see it creates a copy of the bag:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    // Short path if the bag is empty
    if (m_headList == null)
        return new List<T>().GetEnumerator(); // empty list

    bool lockTaken = false;
    try
    {
        FreezeBag(ref lockTaken);
        return ToList().GetEnumerator();
    }
    finally
    {
        UnfreezeBag(lockTaken);
    }
}
```

Like its name implies, `ToList()` returns a `List<T>` (it's not the extension method, it's a private member function).

As a side note, that `return new List<T>().GetEnumerator();` line isn't pretty... that could have written `return Enumerable.Empty<T>().GetEnumerator();` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! :)